# C# - variables from method A as argument of method B

Tags: c#, methods

It's my first post here, so hello everyone. I just started learning C# and have little problem with methods.

To the hearth of the matter - I have to create program, which, at first, asks user about informations and then will print it through another method.
It is only piece of code:

```
namespace Uczymy3
{
    class Student
    {
        public static void GetStudentInformation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student's first name: ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student's birth date: ");
            DateTime birthDay = new DateTime();
            birthDay = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        public static void PrintStudentData(ref string firstName, ref DateTime birthDay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Student {0} was born in {1}", firstName, birthDay);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student.GetStudentInformation();
            XXXX;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem starts at **XXXX**. I want to do something like:
Student.PrintStudentData(Student.GetStudentInformation().firstName, ...)

But I know that's wrong.
**So, how to input variables from one method as another method's arguments?**

Or maybe should I put results of GetStudenInformation() as variables in class Student scope and then use them as arguments in PrintStudentData?

I hope everything is clearly explained.

Comment: create Properties instead of local variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use non static student class and define fields in the class body outside methods.

```
class Student
{

string firstName;
DateTime birthDay;


    public void GetStudentInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter student's first name: ");
        firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter student's birth date: ");

        birthDay = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public void PrintStudentData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Student {0} was born in {1}", firstName, birthDay);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        var myStudent = new Student();
        myStudent.GetStudentInformation();
        myStudent.PrintStudentData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better off creating a Student Entity class and make the first method return it and pass it to the second method. Like this.

```
namespace Uczymy3
{
    class Student
    {     

     class StudentInfo{
      string firstName {get; set;}
      DateTime birthDay {get;set;}
     }
        public static StudentInfo GetStudentInformation()
        {
            StudentInfo info = new StudentInfo();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student's first name: ");
            info.firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student's birth date: ");
            info.birthDay = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            return info;
        }
        public static void PrintStudentData(StudentInfo info)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Student {0} was born in {1}", info.firstName, info.birthDay);
        }
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var info = Student.GetStudentInformation();
            PrintStudentData(info);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this solve your problem? Instantiate an object of the class `Student`. If you want to print the data, simply call the method `PrintStudentData` on the object. That's a more object oriented approach.

PS: try to avoid unnecessary public static methods. Google the topic, it will give you a lot of new insights.

```
namespace Uczymy3
{
    class Student
    {
        private readonly string firstName;
        private readonly DateTime birthDay;

        public Student(string firstName, DateTime birthDay)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.birthDay = birthDay;
        }

        public void PrintStudentData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Student {0} was born in {1}", firstName, birthDay);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student's first name: ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student's birth date: ");
            DateTime birthDay = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); /* not really a user friendly way, but ok :) */

            Student student = new Student(firstName, birthDay);
            student.PrintStudentData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I set 'public' to get access to these methods, but thanks for comment :D

Comment: @Szkaplerny, the public is not the problem, the static is.

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe should I put results of GetStudenInformation() as variables
>   in class Student scope and then use them as arguments in
>   PrintStudentData?

That is exactly what you should do.
Your code should look as follows:

```
var studentInfo = Student.GetStudentInformation();
Student.PrintStudentData(studentInfo.Firstname, studentInfo.BirthDay);
```

In order for this code to be valid you will have to return an instance of Student from Student.GetStudentInformation().

Since you already have a Student class, add [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to it and create a constructor that would set those properties:

```
class Student {
   public string Firstname { get; private set; }
   public DateTime BirthDay { get; private set; }

   public Student(string firstname, DateTime birthDay) {
      Firstname = firstname;
      BirthDay = birthDay;
   }

   ...
}
```

Now you should be able to return an instance of student from GetStudentInformation():

```
public static Student GetStudentInformation()
{
            ...
            return new Student(firstName, birthDay);
}
```

By the way, the arguments of PrintStudentData should not be "ref" in this case.
"ref" means that you pass those arguments [by reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) instead of by value.

Comment: So should I use 'out' option? Somewhere I read that one of differences between 'ref' and 'out' is that 'out' variable must be initialise in method's body. But in my example variables weren't initialized in Print's body, so I chose 'ref'.
How should I do?

Comment: @Szkaplerny "out" means that you are passing the variable by reference but you are also allowing the function to change the reference itself(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx). All instances of classes in C# are automatically passed by reference, unless they are primitives (String, Integer, Boolean, etc...). But in your case there is no need to pass firstName and birthDay by reference because you are just outputing them.